# Redirect 2nd domain back to a specific location on main domain

Tags: nginx, nginx-reverse-proxy, nginx-config

Using Nginx as a Reverse Proxy with a local Tomcat instance. Need to redirect a second domain (example2.com) to a specific request path inside our main domain `example.com`  e.g. `example2.com/** => example.com/urlService/**`. If we type `example2.com/foo` into the browser, it should take us to `example.com/urlService/foo`. Able to access it when I use the complete request path e.g. `example2.com/urlService/foo`.

Used the following reverse-proxy tutorial [see here](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-encrypt-tomcat-8-connections-with-apache-or-nginx-on-ubuntu-16-04#(option-2)-http-proxying-with-nginx) to setup nginx.

```
tomcat hook to njinx
upstream tomcat {
    server 127.0.0.1:8080 fail_timeout=0;
}

server {
    server_name example.com example2.com;
    listen [::]:443 ssl ipv6only=on; # managed by Certbot
    listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot

#    ssl stuff here (left out);

        location / {
                # First attempt to serve request as file, then
                # as directory, then fall back to displaying a 404.
                #try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
                include proxy_params;
                proxy_pass http://tomcat/;
        }

}


server {
    listen 80;
    server_name example.com;
    rewrite ^/(.*) https://example.com/$1 permanent;
}
```

Comment: Why do you have `server_name example.com example2.com;` in the first `server` block?

Comment: remove  example2.com from there?

Comment: If your site uses `https` you need three `server` blocks listening on port 443. One for each of your domains and one as a `default_server`.

Comment: I have all my domains (https)  listed on one line in the first server block, You only 2 because I removed the others to keep things simple for this post - I think its allowed.

Comment: example2.com should point to a specific location only.

Comment: Your other two `server` blocks are unrelated. They only handle connections using `http`. Don't confuse http vs https and example.com vs example2.com.

Comment: I see what you mean. I removed the last server block (example2.com) to keep things simple and focused on the main task. Now how do I get `example2.com/**` to point to the resources located in `example.com/urlService/**` e.g. when I request `example2.com/foo` I should get back the resource in located in `example.com/urlService/foo`?

Comment: In the `server` block for `example2.com`, you may be able to use `proxy_pass http://tomcat/urlService/;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Trying to proxy `https://example2.com/foo` to `https://example.com/urlService/foo` without redirection could be simple or fraught with problems. The main potential problem is resolving URLs generated by the requested pages.

However, a general solution might look like this:

```
upstream tomcat {
    ...
}

server {
    server_name example.com;
    listen 443 ssl;
    ...
    location / {
        ...
        proxy_pass http://tomcat/;
    }    
}    
server {
    server_name example2.com;
    listen 443 ssl;
    ...
    location / {
        ...
        proxy_pass http://tomcat/urlService/;
    }    
}    
server {
    listen 443 ssl default_server;
    ...
    return 301 https://example.com/;
}
server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
}
```

The first `server` block is your main site. The second `server` block proxies into a subfolder of your main site.

The *optional* third server block matches `https` requests that do not match either of your domain names (e.g. IP address access). It needs an SSL certificate, which can be the same as your main site. The browser will complain - but it stops access to the main site using an invalid domain name. Either redirect to the main site or reject the connections with a `return 444;`.

The final `server` block is a generic `http` to `https` redirector.